# Is it possible to have a QScrollbar with tow buttons on each side?

Tags: python, pyqt, slider

I'm looking for a way to have two buttons on each side of a Qscrollbar.
Like that I could have one button to make small step (+ or - 1 on the slider) and the other to make big step (like +10 -10 on the slider)

The example below gives :

[image]

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys


class Viewer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Viewer, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.mainVBOX_param_scene = QVBoxLayout()

        self.paramPlotV = QVBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalSliders = QScrollBar(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalSliders.setMinimum(0)
        self.horizontalSliders.setMaximum(10)
        self.horizontalSliders.setPageStep(1)

        self.paramPlotV.addWidget(self.horizontalSliders)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.paramPlotV)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Windows')
    ex = Viewer(app)
    ex.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But I would like something like :

[image]

Comment: Is this specifically for a separate QScrollBar, or is it for use with an embedded scroll-bar (such as in a text-edit or item-view)?

Comment: It is for a separate QScrollBar where I display Matplotlib figure in it. Qscrollbar is used to display different part of a signal.

Comment: A simple solution would be to put the scroll-bar in its own layout and add a tool-button at each end.